# Disable input fields when clicking the other input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I want to disable selected input fields when the one of the chosen inputs is clicked.

Example:
1. User selects input field "Name" and input field "Company" and "Company Number" is disabled;
2. The field is disabled upon "entering" into field, not writting in it.

This was my code; it works, but not exactly as intended. It disables when user starts typing. I want to disable it on "enter"/on click.

```js
var disableField = function () {
  var state = document.getElementById("name").value.length > 0;
  document.getElementById("company").disabled = state;
  document.getElementById("number").disabled = state;
};
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try writing on onfocus event isntead of onkeyup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you tagged your question under jQuery then why not you tried some jQuery! use something like this-

```
<script>
$('#elementId').click(function(){
  $("#someElementId").attr('disabled', true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wow! That's brilliant and so easy. Thank you so much!

Comment: your're welcome :) if this works for you then don't forget to upvote it.

Comment: I tried, but I can't upvote since I don't have enough reputation (which is 15+), but man - you just saved me alot of work! Huge thanks, I know its not the same as +1 rep, but keep in mind someone will have a better weekend! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.onfocus` event.

```
// name, company, company_number are the elements

function func(){
    if(this.value.length == 0) company_number.disabled = true;
    else company_number.disabled = false;
}

name.onfocus = func;
company.onfocus = func;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `onfocus` event like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" onfocus="disableField()"/>
```

This event activates when you click and the focus is set in the input field.

The opposite event (when clicking out of the field) is `onblur`

Comment: Yes, I've tried it but with no result (on Chrome/FFx at least there's no action; it behaves the same as onkeyup). Thanks for the reply.